# How to detach JRuby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jruby, daemon, jrubyonrails

I created a small application using Ruby on Rails and I recently transferred it to JRuby.

The issue I have is before when I was using MRI, I used to run the server using `rails server -d` to run it in the background.

Now with JRuby, it seems that this option is not available and I can't just leave it in the background.

Is there a way to do this? I've found a few threads on how to this using gems like `spoon` but I can't find any documentation on how to install then implement it on my application

Also, it seems the answers I found are little out dated.

I was wondering, are there new gems out there that can be easily installed/used to run a JRuby on Rails app in the background?

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You can at least use another server, like `thin`, to run Rails. Anything that can run Rack applications should work.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what OS you are using, but on linux/unix you can put any command into the background by placing an "&" after it.  for example

```
rails server &
```

or if you have it running a cntl-z and then bg should place it into the background as well.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 13.04.

I tried using both methods you gave me. The first method of adding a "&" at the end didn't work. When using the command, it would run the process a few moments after entering the command. It didn't run as a background process. 

Using ctrl-z stopped my application instead of keeping it running.

Comment: you have to type bg on the command line after cntl-z ... but that should not really be any different from placing an & at the end of the command.  What makes you think adding the & only worked for a few moments, did you get an error message? ... type jobs from the command prompt to see what jobs are running in the background in that terminal window ... (btw closing the terminal will kill the job)

Comment: When I entered the command rails server & I got this message:

[1] 24109

Which should be the PID.

But then, a few seconds later my terminal is showing the process starting up:


=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.2.12 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server

Comment: so it is running in the background,  if you don't want to see the output you can use rails -s > /dev/null 2>&1 &

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu it has to be
rails s -d &

The -d stands for run in detached mode.
the & is standard UNIX for command line detach.

Comment: The -d command would not work with JRuby. 

You will get this error:

NotImplementedError: fork is not available on this platform

For regular Ruby this would be fine.  But the solution to this was to add "nohup" so all the output text will just be stored in a file in the rails app folder.